# Matlab make half of the image blank

Tags: matlab, resize, imshow, imread

Got an issue on matlab, trying to make half of the image blank without resizing to it.
ATM im using that simple code

```
im=imread('spinpie.bmp');
n=fix(size(im,1)/2);
A=im(n+1:end,:,:);
imshow(A)
```

And im geting this:

[image]

What is actually i need to have is something like this:

[image]

Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
im=imread('spinpie.bmp');
n=fix(size(im,1)/2);
A = repmat(255,size(im));           %// PreAllocating with white pixels
A(n+1:end,:,:) = im(n+1:end,:,:);   %// Assigning only the required pixels to original image
imshow(uint8(A));                   %// lastly converting double to uint8 before displaying
```